# Ignore @mentions wrapped in links

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Hi I've got a script that parses @mentions into links, but this needs to be loaded more than once and currently it breaks things it has already parsed as links so i need to get it to ignore @mentions already wrapped in a tags but I can't see to get it working.

This is what I have so far: 
`/((?:^|[^a-zA-Z0-9_!#$%&*@＠]|RT:?))([@＠])([a-zA-Z0-9_\.]{1,20})(\/[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]{0,24})?/g`

An example string is:

```
Hi @andre Hi <a href="">@jane</a>
```

`@andre` should be wrapped in the a tag like `@jane` is, and `@jane` is already in a tag `<a href="">@jane</a>` and should be ignored.

Comment: Please give an example string. your picture is better

Comment: You should give some expected inputs and outputs. Also why you regex does not work.

Comment: So, if `([@＠])([a-zA-Z0-9_\.]{1,20})` is a `@mention`, and you yourself wrapped them, considering every time you wrapped a `@whatever`, you wrapped it into a `...@whatever</a>`, wouldn't be enough to get just all `@mention`s that are not followed by a `<a/>`? If so, this regex would work: `(?!([@＠])([a-zA-Z0-9_\.]{1,20})</a>)([@＠])([a-zA-Z0-9_\.]{1,20})`.

Comment: See demo: http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=(%3F!(%5B%40%EF%BC%A0%5D)(%5Ba-zA-Z0-9_%5C.%5D%7B1%2C20%7D)%3C%2Fa%3E)(%5B%40%EF%BC%A0%5D)(%5Ba-zA-Z0-9_%5C.%5D%7B1%2C20%7D)&input=Hi%20%40andre%20Hi%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22%22%3E%40jane%3C%2Fa%3E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Description

This regex will capture the naked `@names` which are not already wrapped inside like this `<a href="">@jane</a>`

Regex `(?!>)([@＠])([a-zA-Z0-9_\.]{1,20})\b(?!<)`

Replace with `<a href="">$0</a>`

[image]

Input text: `Hi @andre Hi <a href="http://some.url">@jane</a>`

Output text: `Hi <a href="">@andre</a> Hi <a href="http://some.url">@jane</a>`

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this question was because I was converting @mentions to links on the fly, and I was loading additional content which had @mentions to replace. I was running a linkify function to link every match which was causing issues.

I couldn't get the provided answers in the comments to work so I tried a different approach.

I know where the additional content was being added (before a static button) so I used the jquery slice function to select what elements to run the function on.

```
var linkify = $('.user-profile-feed-item').slice(-4).find('.linkify');
```

This way also the function only runs for what is needed without having to resort to additional regex filtering.